# React onhover toggle html inside div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a div with some toggle features

```
  <div className={styles.divStyle} onMouseEnter={this.hover} onMouseOut={this.hover}>
```

and heres the function

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isToggle: false
    };
    this.hover = this.hover.bind(this);
  }

  hover(e) {
    this.setState({
      isToggle: !this.state.isToggle
    });
  }
```

its working to toggle display hidden and display block of some icons inside that div

```
<i style={{display: this.state.isToggle ? 'block': 'none'}} class="fa fa-chain"/>
```

but whenever I mouse over the icons or the image I have inside the div, it counts as a mouseout, I want the items inside the div to count as the div for the toggle function, I made a sample of what im talking about in a codepen. Mouse over the image or the text

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wjKXqQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want `onMouseLeave`:

```
<section onMouseEnter={this.hover} onMouseLeave={this.hover}>
```

Updated pen: https://codepen.io/acdcjunior/pen/pVjZzg

More on [`mouseleave` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave) (bold is mine):

> The **`mouseleave`** event is fired when the pointer of a pointing device
>   (usually a mouse) is moved out of an element that has the listener
>   attached to it.
>
> `mouseleave` and `mouseout` are similar but differ in that `mouseleave` does
>   not bubble and `mouseout` does. 
>  This means that `mouseleave` is fired when
>   the pointer has **exited the element *and* all of its descendants**, whereas
>   `mouseout` is fired when the pointer leaves the element *or* leaves one of
>   the element's descendants (even if the pointer is still within the
>   element).

Answer (score -1):

Your used event is wrong choice for this work. Use `onMouseOver` event

Comment: could you explain a bit more, or provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: Adding mouseOver also causes the same issue of flickering on hover. Correct solution would be to use mouseEnter and mouseLeave. as correctly explained above.